# how to call directly z-index in class in html?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

> Ask a question is it applicable to do these in the element:
> `<div class="z-index-2"> <div>`
> if its right or wrong?
> Blockquote

Comment: You mean `element.style.zIndex`?

Answer (score 0):

class X applies bunch of styles in css written for .X selector. so it is just a name. if you have no "z-index-2" specific class then it won't work. you can modify inline styles instead

```
<div style="z-index: 2;"> </div>
```